Meaning of negative vertex coordinate in Wavefront obj file
I have a Wavefront obj file which seems to be parsed mostly fine but there's one detail I'm unclear on.
I have a line like:
'v 0.3062 0.5400 0'
Which works fine
(Note that the third coordinate is always 0, because my object is 2D.)
However, sometimes the X or Y coordinate goes below 0, and I am not sure what this means.
Does that specific coordinate get clipped?
I haven't seen an explanation online (I did read about 'vt'/texture coordinates sometimes going below 0 to indicate tiling). Would be appreciative of any answers.
Thanks in advance.

What do you observe to happen with a negative value?
